# How can I tunnel Telnet connections between two interfaces?

Tags: linux, networking, network-programming, telnet, tunnel

I have the following network:

```
PC1 --|¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯|                            |¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯|-- board2
PC2 --| gateway |-- (eth0) [server] (eth1) --| gateway |
PC3 --|_________|                            |_________|-- board1
```

As you can see, the server (running Linux) has 2 interfaces so that the PCs and embedded boards are not on the same subnetwork.

I would like to develop a simple application (or use an existing one) that tunnels incomming Telnet connections from `eth0` (using a specific port) to boards through `eth1`.

I **don't have root privileges** on the server, but I have a regular Unix account. I don't want the PCs to actually "log in" to the server; I just want them to pass through it to connect to the boards. The server has Python, PHP and Perl installed.

I want to support multiple connections. The port number could be used to forward the connection to the right board (say I have 10 boards, then the tunnel listens on ports 3000 to 3009).

I can imagine a simple Web application to do that, but I want a native Telnet connection that will support CTRL+C and all that stuff and allow you to use any terminal emulator on the PCs (i.e. PuTTY or another one), which run Windows.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for a TCP *proxy*.  A proxy accepts connections on one port, connects to another ip/port, and then passes traffic back and forth.

If you have `xinetd` on your system you already have what you need.  The `redirect` directive for a service causes xinetd to open a connection to another host/port and act as a proxy.  See [this document](http://www.linuxfocus.org/English/November2000/article175.shtml) for an example.

[balance](http://www.inlab.de/balance.html) is another very simple proxy tool that will do what you need.  This is probably easier to run as a non-`root` user, especially since it's configured entirely on the command line.

Since you're not `root` on your server you'll need to run these on ports > 1024, but otherwise you should be all set.

Comment: I'll look into this. Is it possible your _balance_ link isn't the right one?

Comment: Hah, yes, Firefox ate my clipboard.

Comment: I guess I will have to start `balance` multiple times then if I want my multiple-port forwarding to work? Something like: `balance 12.15.0.2 3000 10.0.0.15:23`, and a second one `balance 12.5.0.2 3001 10.0.0.16:23` and so on (where 12.15.0.2 is `eth0`'s address)?

Comment: Yeah.  You could use something like [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/) to manage multiple processes sanely.  There may be other proxy solutions that only require a single command and a config file to handle multiple proxies.

Comment: What if the outgoing address doesn't exist yet? Does the proxy usually connect to the destination when it's started or when there's an incomming connection matching said destination?

Comment: The proxy will typically only initiate a connection to the remote system when it receives a connection on the listening port.  If the remote port isn't available at this point, you're connection attempt will fail...which is pretty much what would happen without the proxy.